# Qt(c++) Keybinding with button(for my developing application)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I want to write a function that will work with keybinding for the application I am developing on the Qt platform, but I could not find any example that will work for me, like the picture I added from the discord application, can you help me?

[Discord keybinding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIsFH.png)

Comment: You can have a look on this one: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html

Comment: I don't want to assign it to a key, I want the person to choose the key they want. Thank you for feedback but i think i checked more pages about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want user to hit a key combination for a selection then just create a class inheriting `QLinEdit` (even `QLabel` would work) and override keyPressEvent,
`void QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);`
and then use `QKeyEvent`s function to get key and modifiers (shift, ctrl etc.). Just read the Qt Docs about it. Depending on the key and modifiers, write the modifier name + key's text (e.g. `Ctrl + N`).

To hold actions (`QAction`), just use `std::map<QString,QAction*>` or `QMap<QString,QAction*>` and register/add your `QAction` objects in the map and assuming your class' name is `MyClass` and it has `getKeyString()` , to return key combination as `QString`, then you will just do,

```
QString str = MyClassObj.getKeyString();
QKeySequence ks(str);
actionMap.at("NewFile")->setShortcut(ks);
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is slightly fuzzy, there are a few aspects associated with key bindings.

1. At the start of the application, you can assign default shortcut keys to actions and menus, see the documentation on `QAction`, `QShortcut`, `QMenu`.
2. If you need a dialog which allows changing a key binding, you can easily create a dialog yourself. See the documentation on `QKeySequenceEdit` which helps you entering a new shortcut key sequence for an action.
3. Last but not least, you need to bind your modified key sequences to your actions. You can do this by deriving a class from QAction. Find these actions by searching all objects with `mainWindow->findChildren<YourActionClass*>()`
   and modify the keyboard shortcut with the results from your dialog.
   This derived class could also store the default binding, the icon (your users might like to modify icons perhaps) etc.

All this is quite straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, if you have any example about it, can you share with me?